# string(2) "id" Notice: id was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace:

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

> string(2) "id"
> Notice: id was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php'), wc_get_template_part, load_template, require('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php'), do_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Avada_Woocommerce->output_related_products, woocommerce_related_products, wc_get_template, include('/themes/demo-theme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php'), WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.) in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 5227

Answer (score 2):

This is probabily caused by an old file in yout template while you have a new Woocommerce version. The fix is quite easy, just look for the file "/themes/demo-theme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php" as described in the stack trace and replace:

```
$product->id;
```

with:

```
$product->get_id();
```

That should be done for all the occurrences of "$product->id;" in order to get rid of the warning

Answer (score 0):

> wp-content/themes/Active-Theme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php

```
/*if ( ! $related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page ) ) {
    return;
}*/

$related = wc_get_related_products( $product->get_id(), $posts_per_page );

if ( ! $related ) {
  return;
}

$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
'post_type'            => 'product',
'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
'no_found_rows'        => 1,
'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
'orderby'              => $orderby,
'post__in'             => $related,
'post__not_in'         => array( $product->get_id() )
) );
```